# Prove that $L_n = \alpha^n +\beta^n$ for all integers $n\geq 0$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, lucas-numbers

Let $\alpha =\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$ and $\beta = \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$. Prove that $L_n = \alpha^n +\beta^n$ for all integers $n\geq 0$ where $L_n$ denotes the Lucas numbers.

I managed to solve the base case:
$$L_2 = \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2 = 3$$

I wasn't able to figure out how to proceed with the induction step and the rest of the proof. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is $\alpha$? And $\beta$?

Comment: The question doesn't define them, is there something that they typically represent?

Comment: In that case, you should probably go and look in your book for the definitions, or ask whoever assigned the exercise to you what they mean.

Comment: The Lucas numbers $L_n$ satisfies a linear recurrence relation of the form $L_{n+2} - (\alpha+\beta)L_{n+1} + \alpha\beta L_{n} = 0$. If $\alpha+\beta$, $\alpha\beta$ and $L_1$ are all integers , so does all $L_n$ for $n \ge 2$. (Note 1/ this is true for Lucas numbers, 2/ $L_0 = 2$ is an integer).

Comment: @NickPowers For expression involving Fibonacci and Lucas numbers, it is pretty common to use $\alpha, \beta$ as a shorthand for $\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The crucial fact is that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of $x^2=x+1$ and so $\alpha+\beta=1$. This makes induction work easily:

$L_0 = 2 = 1+1 = \alpha^0+\beta^0$

$L_1 = 1 = \alpha+\beta = \alpha^1+\beta^1$

$L_{n+2}=L_{n+1}+L_n
= \alpha^{n+1}+\beta^{n+1}+\alpha^n+\beta^n
= \alpha^{n+1}+\alpha^n+\beta^{n+1}+\beta^n
$
$\qquad
= \alpha^n(\alpha+1)+ \beta^n(\beta+1)
= \alpha^n\alpha^2+ \beta^n\beta^2
= \alpha^{n+2}+\beta^{n+2}
$

Comment: I'm aware that I should use induction but am unsure what α and β represent so i don't know how to apply it.